# How do we close and a Silverlight application in silverlight 4

Tags: web-applications, silverlight-4.0

I want to close and a silverlight application on the MenuClick event which I am handling in a helper class...

```
if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

or

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("close");
```

is not working.....

So if anyone has a diff solution or corrections to the above approch please answer me...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
   HtmlPage.Window.Eval("window.open('','_self');window.close();");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the app is running in-browser then the browser's rules regarding opening/closing windows will apply. Namely, you can only use a scripted command to close a window that was opened with a scripted command. If the user opened the window then you cannot close it with an `Invoke` command.

I've never tried to close an OOB app in code so I can't help you on that side of things.

Comment: thnksss for the quick reply.. let me explain the exact senario... the user clicked on File--> LogOff and then we should close the existing application and open a new Login application....  I am able to open the new application but the old app is still open....

Comment: That scenario doesn't affect my answer.